# Php If conditions not working with existing array

Tags: php, arrays

This sounds so simple but for some reason its not working on my end.
I have an array which will check if values exist then will act accordingly

My array contains values and my condition is meant to check 2 conditions if value "a" is contained in the array at array index 0 and "b" doesnt exist in array then do this. if value "a" at index 0 and "b" does exist then run another block of code.

```
//THIS CONTAINS ALL THE FIELDS SELECTED
$report_cols = $_POST['report_cols'];
$percent_amt= explode(",",$report_cols);
$n_fields_arr = array();
$b=0;
//This checks if b exists in array
if (array_key_exists('`b`', $percent_amt)) 
{
  $b = 1;
}

if($percent_amt[0] == '`a`' && $b == 0)
{
$report_cols = str_replace("`a`,","",$report_cols);
$report_cols = str_replace(",`a`","",$report_cols);
$report_cols = str_replace(",,",",",$report_cols);
array_push($n_fields_arr,"a");
echo "done";    
}
if($percent_amt[0] == '`a`' && $b == 1)
{
$report_cols = str_replace("`a`,","",$report_cols);
$report_cols = str_replace(",`a`","",$report_cols);
$report_cols = str_replace(",,",",",$report_cols);
$report_cols = str_replace("`b`,","",$report_cols);
$report_cols = str_replace(",`b`","",$report_cols);
$report_cols = str_replace(",,",",",$report_cols);
array_push($n_fields_arr,"a","b");
echo "Done AB"; 
}
```

Error I am having is that its not recongizing the two && section and keeps running the first if statement. If there is a something am missing or a better method your help will be grately appreciated

Comment: First `var_dump($percent_amt[0])` And you __definitely don't have__ `\`b\`` key in exploded array.

Comment: is it possible that the last sentence should say "if value "a" at index 0 *or* "b" does exist then run another block of code"?

Comment: Where is this if else you speak of?

Comment: add parenthesis like if(($percent_amt[0] == '`a`') && ($b == 0))

Comment: I have done that but to no success

Comment: this works for me if(($percent_amt[0] == 'a') && ($b == 1))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`explode()` function explodes array with numeric keys.

use `in_array()` to check `b`.

```
if (in_array('b', $percent_amt)) 
{
  $b = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use strpos to search for an occurrence of a string within a string.
And use an array for the search argument for str_replace.  Which will simplify your code.

```
//$report_cols = $_POST['report_cols'];
$report_cols = '`a`,`foo`,`a`,`b`,`bar`,`b`,';
$n_fields_arr = array();

$b_found = strpos($report_cols, '`b`') !== false ? true : false;
$a_start = strpos($report_cols, '`a`') == 0      ? true : false;

if ($a_start) {
    $report_cols = str_replace(array('`a`','`b`'), '', $report_cols);
    $report_cols = trim(preg_replace('/,+/', ',', $report_cols), ',');
    $n_fields_arr[] = 'a';
    if ($b_found) {
        $n_fields_arr[] = 'b';
    }
}
print $report_cols;
var_dump($n_fields_arr);
```

Output:

```
`foo`,`bar`

array (size=2)
  0 => string 'a' (length=1)
  1 => string 'b' (length=1)
```